# CSV::MalformedCSVError: New line must be <"\n\r">

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.2

Trying to parse this file with Ruby CSV.

https://www.sec.gov/files/data/broker-dealers/company-information-about-active-broker-dealers/bd070219.txt

However, I am getting an error.

```
CSV.open(file_name, "r", { :col_sep => "\t", :row_sep => "\n\r" }).each do |row|
    puts row
end
```

> CSV::MalformedCSVError: New line must be <"\n\r"> not <"\r"> in line
>   1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows row_sep is `"\r\n"`, not `"\n\r"`. However this CSV is malformed. Looking at it using a hex editor it appears to be using `"\r\r\n"`.

It's tab-delimited.

In addition it is not using proper quoting, line 247 has `600 "B" STREET STE. 2204`, so you need to turn off quote characters.

```
quote_char: nil, col_sep: "\t", row_sep: "\r\r\n"
```

There's an extra tab on the end, each line ends with `\t\r\r\n`. You can also look at it as using a row_sep of `"\r\n"` with an extra `\r` field.

```
quote_char: nil, col_sep: "\t", row_sep: "\r\n"
```

Or you can view it as having a row_sep of `\t\r\r\n` and no extra field.

```
quote_char: nil, col_sep: "\t", row_sep: "\t\r\r\n"
```

Either way, it's a mess.

---

I used a [hex editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_editor) to look at the file as text and raw data side by side. This let me see what's truly at the end of the line.

```
87654321  0011 2233 4455 6677 8899 aabb ccdd eeff  0123456789abcdef                       
00000000: 3030 3030 3030 3139 3034 0941 4252 4148  0000001904.ABRAH
00000010: 414d 2053 4543 5552 4954 4945 5320 434f  AM SECURITIES CO
00000020: 5250 4f52 4154 494f 4e09 3030 3832 3934  RPORATION.008294
00000030: 3532 0933 3732 3420 3437 5448 2053 5452  52.3724 47TH STR
00000040: 4545 5420 4354 2e20 4e57 0920 0947 4947  EET CT. NW. .GIG
00000050: 2048 4152 424f 5209 5741 0939 3833 3335   HARBOR.WA.98335
00000060: 090d 0d0a 3030 3030 3030 3233 3033 0950  ....0000002303.P
          ^^^^^^^^^
```

[Hex 09 0d 0d 0a](https://hextables.com/list-of-conversion-tables/hex-to-utf-8-table/) is `\t\r\r\n`.

Alternatively, you can print the lines with [`p`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-p) and any invisible characters will be revealed.

```
f = File.open(file_name)
p f.readline

"0000001904\tABRAHAM SECURITIES CORPORATION\t00829452\t3724 47TH STREET CT. NW\t \tGIG HARBOR\tWA\t98335\t\r\r\n"
```

Comment: "\r\n" returns CSV::MalformedCSVError: New line must be <"\r\n"> not <"\r"> in line 1.

Comment: How did you identify this so I can trouble shoot in the future?

Comment: @user2012677 Great question! I used a [hex editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_editor) to look at what's really in the file plus a [UTF8/ASCII hex table](https://hextables.com/list-of-conversion-tables/hex-to-utf-8-table/). 09 is tab, 0d is \r, 0a is \n. Alternatively you can print out the lines in the file with [`p`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-p) and it will show `\t\r\r\n` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Use `:row_sep => :auto` instead of `:row_sep => "\n\r"`:

```rb
CSV.open(file_name, "r", { :col_sep => "\t", :row_sep => :auto }).each do |row|
    puts row
end
```

Comment: :auto returns CSV::MalformedCSVError: New line must be <"\r"> not <"\n"> in line 3.

Comment: Weird, I'm on a Mac, could that change things?

Comment: Okay, yeah, on Mac it thorws